# A PHP for loop isn't displaying content from a file

Tags: php, html, for-loop, html-table, echo

I have a script that is supposed to output certain parameters from a text file stored on the server.  This is my source code (sorry about the formatting):

```html
<?php
  $traw = file_get_contents("path/to/transactions.file");
  $lns = explode("\n",$traw);
  $mode['t'] = false;
  $mode['c'] = false;
  $mode['f'] = false;
  # $t = array();
  # $f = array();
  $fs=0;
  $ts=0;
  for($i=0;$i<count($lns);$i++){
      $ln = $lns[0];
      if($ln=="==START TRANSACTION DATA=="){$mode['t']=true;}
      elseif($ln=="=START CLIENT INFO="){$mode['c']=true;}
      elseif($ln=="=END CLIENT INFO="){$mode['c']=false;}
      elseif($ln=="==END TRANSACTION DATA=="){$mode['t']=false;$ts++;}
      elseif($ln=="==START FAILED TRANSACTION=="){$mode['f']=true;}
      elseif($ln=="==END FAILED TRANSACTION=="){$mode['f']=false;$fs++;}
      else{
          if($mode['t'] && $mode['c']){
              $kv = explode(": ",$ln);
              $t[$ts]['client'][strtolower($kv[0])] = $kv[1]; // set key to value in client data
          }
          elseif($mode['t'] && !$mode['c']){
              $kv = explode(": ",$ln);
              $t[$ts]['p'][strtolower($kv[0])] = $kv[1]; // set key to value in purchase data
          }
          elseif($mode['f']){
              $kv = explode(": ",$ln);
              $f[$fs][strtolower($kv[0])] = $kv[1]; // set key to value in failed data
          }
          else{
              continue; // This line means nothing, and is most likely blank
          }
      }
  }
  for($i=0;$i<count($t);$i++){
      $d = $t[$i];
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['photo id'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['print'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['quantity'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['price'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['date'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['additional info'].'</td>';
      echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.$d['client']['address'].'">'.$d['client']['name'].'</button><a href="mailto:'.$d['client']['email'].'">&lt;'.$d['client']['email'].'&gt;</a></td>';
      echo '</tr>';
  }
  for($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++){
      $d = $f[$i];
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>-</td>';
      echo '<td>-</td>';
      echo '<td>-</td>';
      echo '<td>-</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$d['date'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>-</td>';
      echo '<td>-</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
  }
  print_r($t);
  print_r($f);
?>
```

This is output within a standard HTML `<tbody>` element.  I know that the transactions file is loaded properly, since in testing the script output the file correctly.  I also know that the script iterates the correct number of times, since if I use `echo $i`, it returns the expected result.  However, nothing outputs in the table when I run the script.

This is the content of the transactions file:

```
==START FAILED TRANSACTION==
Date: 05-2-2017 (Sunday, February 5th, 2017) UTC
==END FAILED TRANSACTION==

==START FAILED TRANSACTION==
Date: 05-2-2017 (Sunday, February 5th, 2017) UTC
==END FAILED TRANSACTION==

==START FAILED TRANSACTION==
Date: 05-2-2017 (Sunday, February 5th, 2017) UTC
==END FAILED TRANSACTION==

==START FAILED TRANSACTION==
Date: 05-2-2017 (Sunday, February 5th, 2017) UTC
==END FAILED TRANSACTION==

==START FAILED TRANSACTION==
Date: 05-2-2017 (Sunday, February 5th, 2017) UTC
==END FAILED TRANSACTION==

==START TRANSACTION DATA==
=START CLIENT INFO=
Address: {ADDR}
Name: {NAME}
Email: {EMAIL}
=END CLIENT INFO=
Inventory ID: {INV}
Photo ID: {ID}
Quantity: {QTY}
Print: {PRNT}
Price: {PRC}
Date of transaction: {DATE}
Raw Braintree transaction data: {TRNS}
Additional info: {ADTL}
==END TRANSACTION DATA==
```

This is probably a very obvious mistake that I made!

P.S. The page uses Bootstrap and jQuery, if that affects anything.

P.P.S. Side problem:  Any `echo` statements output outside of the table for some reason.  Not especially important, as long as the table rows and cells are inside.

Comment: I noticed in the code you don't have ``<table>`` tags... were they just excluded here or did you forget them? Also rather than apologise for formatting - why not just fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance it seems the first loop doesnt index by your loop-variable, you just get element at position zero:

`$ln = $lns[0]`

should probably be:

```
$ln = $lns[$i]
```

Also when you say "I also know that the script iterates the correct number of times", have you checked all loops and tried printing the expected value?

Comment: As a comment, I believe PHP have a foreach statement you can use to avoid these types of bugs.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch this, thanks!  The script would still iterate the correct number of times, but it would only evaluate the first line infinitely.